# Fail to add the first orderer to a channel. Error: invalid join block: cannot enable channel capabilities without orderer support first

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I’m trying to create a channel with hyperledger fabric v2.3 (no system channel) fallowing docs for [creating a channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html#create-a-channel).
And I failed to [add first orderer to a channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html#step-two-use-the-osnadmin-cli-to-add-the-first-orderer-to-the-channel). Please tell me what makes the error.

I tried (succeed, maybe):

```
configtxgen -profile SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft -outputBlock genesis_block00.pb -channelID channel00

2021-03-24 01:23:40.832 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2021-03-24 01:23:40.837 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
2021-03-24 01:23:40.837 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216 
2021-03-24 01:23:40.837 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /root/fabric/configtx.yaml
2021-03-24 01:23:40.838 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 005 Generating genesis block
2021-03-24 01:23:40.838 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Creating application channel genesis block
2021-03-24 01:23:40.838 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
```

and tried :

```
export OSN_TLS_CA_ROOT_CERT=$FABRIC_CFG_PATH/orgs/ordorg/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt
export ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT=$FABRIC_CFG_PATH/orgs/ordorg/users/ordadmin/msp/admincerts/ordadmin-cert.pem
export ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=$FABRIC_CFG_PATH/orgs/ordorg/users/ordadmin/msp/keystore/server.key

osnadmin channel join -o localhost:7080 --ca-file $OSN_TLS_CA_ROOT_CERT --client-cert $ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT --client-key $ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY --channelID channel00  --config-block genesis_block00.pb
```

This makes **error** :

```
Status: 400
{
 "error": "invalid join block: cannot enable channel capabilities without orderer support first"
}
```

There're my [**orderer org tree**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqmee.jpg)

environment variables for the **orderer**

```
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/keystore/server.key
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]
export ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=ordorgMSP
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/keystore/server.key
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]
export ORDERER_FILELEDGER_LOCATION=/root/fabric/legder/ordorg/ord1
export ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=localhost:7080
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/keystore/server.key
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[/root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt]
```

and **configtx.yaml**

```yaml
Organizations:
    - &ordorg
        Name: ordorg
        ID: ordorgMSP
        MSPDir: /root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ordadmin/msp/
        Policies: &ordorgPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ordorgMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ordorgMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('ordorgMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - localhost:7050

    - &peer1
        Name: peer1
        ID: peer1MSP
        MSPDir: /root/fabric/orgs/peer1/users/peer1admin/msp/
        Policies: &peer1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peer1MSP.admin', 'peer1MSP.peer', 'peer1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peer1MSP.admin', 'peer1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peer1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('peer1MSP.peer')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: localhost
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilitie
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
 
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
            - Host: localhost
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: /root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt
              ServerTLSCert: /root/fabric/orgs/ordorg/users/ord1/msp/tlscacerts/ca.crt

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies: 
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers" 
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Organizations:
                - <<: *ordorg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *ordorgPolicies
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *peer1
                  Policies:
                      <<: *peer1Policies
```

Comment: the orderer section lost `orderer.capabilities` part. I added `Capabilities: <<: *OrdererCapabilities`
under Profiles.SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft.Orderer. It works

Comment: Not sure if it's a cut and paste error, but under the `Capabilities` section,  *&OrdererCapabilitie* should be *&OrdererCapabilities*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a cut and paste error, but under the `Capabilities` section,  ***&OrdererCapabilitie*** should be ***&OrdererCapabilities***